# python convert date and time into linux timestmap

Tags: python, date, timestamp

i have timestamps in the following format:

```
2011 February 2nd  13h 27min 21s
110202             132721
```

I want to convert 110202 132721 into the corresponding linux timestamp: 1296682041

Is there any quick efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> s =  "110202 132721"
>>> print time.mktime(time.strptime(s, "%y%m%d %H%M%S"))
1296653241.0
```

This interprets the time as a local time (your current time zone).

Comment: @AYBABTU: A capital `Y` would mean a four-digit year.  Since the string `s` contains a two-digit year, we have to use the lower case `y` here.  See http://ideone.com/uv1jR6 -- the first `print` works, the second throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Unix timestamp, use the `time.mktime(t)` function. It takes a `time.struct_time` object.

The objects definition can be viewed [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time). So you just have to parse the date and the time and put it into the object before handing it over to the `mktime()` function

Answer (score 1):

Without your timezone information, this is not the 'corresponding' unix timestamp.

After a few attempts I have guessed you could be located in the Pacific coast of USA, so you have to define it explicitely in your script:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import calendar

a = "110202 132721"
yourTZ = 'America/Los_Angeles'

calendar.timegm(pytz.timezone(yourTZ).localize(datetime.strptime(a, '%y%m%d %H%M%S')).utctimetuple())

# returns 1296682041
```